# Spring security and thymeleaf login issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm writing this post because i have problem with login which I can't resolve for a long time. 
The point is, that I am trying to make login using Spring MVC, Spring Security and Thymeleaf. Versions of these are:
Spring 4.1.5
Spring Security 4.0.1
Thymeleaf 2.1.4 but this Thymeleaf extras-springsecurity4 is 2.1.2.

After many issues I almost copied everything from example project at thymeleaf's page.

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>admm</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My spring-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.admm" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />


    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <property name="additionalDialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

        <import resource="applicationContext-security.xml" />

    </beans>
```

applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Authentication using a memory user list -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jim" password="demo" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="demo" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="ted" password="demo" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- Login pages -->
        <form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-failure-url="/login-error.html" />
        <logout />
        <!-- Security zones -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shared/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    </http>

</beans:beans>
```

and my login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login page</h1>
        <p>Example administrator: jim / demo</p>
        <p>Example user: bob / demo</p>
        <p>Example user and administrator: ted / demo</p>
        <p th:if="${loginError}" class="error">Wrong user or password</p>
        <form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post">
            <label for="j_username">Username</label>:
            <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" autofocus="autofocus" /> <br />
            <label for="j_password">Password</label>:
            <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </form>
        <p><a href="../index.html" th:href="@{/index.html}">Back to home page</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the problem is that when i hit login button it appends /j_spring_security_check to URL so I have smh like this: http://localhost:8080/admm/j_spring_security_check
and on page shows error:
HTTP Status 404 - /admm/j_spring_security_check

type Status report

message /admm/j_spring_security_check

description The requested resource is not available.

How can I resolve this problem? Do you need any more details to help me? I would be really thankful for any help

Comment: I suggest a read of the reference guide... In Spring 4 the login url is `/login` and not `/j_spring_security_check`. and The names of the fields need to be `username` and `password` in other words remove the `j_` prefix.

Comment: Also check your spelling! I don't know if this is just your typo or what:     HTTP Status 404 - /admm/j_spring_security_check
  type Status report
  message /admm/j_spring_security_check
  where it should probably be "admin"